# Qt C++ Slot is not called when Signal is sent

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slots

After debugging, I'm sure that the replyFinish() slot is not called when I call this->getNetReply(). These are my files, in the main() fumction I call the getNetReply this way: Networking a; a.getNetReply();
I did add  QT+=network to my qmake. 
Please help me. Thank you very much.

my networking.cpp file

```
#include "networking.h"
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>

// constructor    

void Networking::getNetReply(){
    QNetworkAccessManager *man  = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QObject::connect(man, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));
    qDebug() << "connected";
    QNetworkRequest req;
    req.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
    man->get(req);

}
// this method not called
void Networking::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
    QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
    QString str = QString(data);
    this->netRep = str;
    code = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
}
```

my networking.h header file:

```
#ifndef NETWORKING_H
#define NETWORKING_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>

class Networking : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QString netRep;
    int code;
    explicit Networking(QObject *parent = 0);
    void getNetReply();

public slots:
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply*);

};

#endif // NETWORKING_H
```

Comment: Can you show the whole `main()` function too?

Comment: Maybe you should check if `connect` method returns ok or failure. On the other hand, you can try to clean and rebuild the moc of the class. remarks: `Networkig` is `QObject` because of this you don't need to write `QObject::` on `connect` method. All classes that inherits from `QObject`has a member called `connect`.

Comment: Your code is good and it should work. Make sure that firewalls or antivirus don't block your app.

Comment: This is a strange problem. I did do this downloader more than one thousand times and this is the first time I run into that problem. I think I should delete my project and stop working.

Comment: You could connect to the `error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)` signal of the `QNetworkReply` and check if that gives an indication of what's going wrong. I don't think think the `finished()` signal is emitted in the error case.

Answer (score 0):

The get() function returns a QNetworkReply object. Connect to the error signal of that object and it will tell you if an error happens (and which).